# Change background color opacity without changing background image opacity

Tags: html, css

I want to increase button's background color brightness when user hovers it. But I wanna do that irrespective of the color a button has. Bellow, you can see four buttons. Only the last one works, because it has `:hover` handler explicitly configured for yellow color.

```css
.hoverme {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    background-color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverme:hover .inner {
    /*
   Pseudocode:
     background-color-opacity: 1;
    */
}
.hoverme .inner {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.hoverme.red .inner {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.9);
}
.hoverme.green .inner {
    background-color: rgba(0,200,0,.9);
}
.hoverme.yellow .inner {
    background-color: rgba(250,240,0,.9);
}

.hoverme.yellow.works-but-not-nice:hover .inner {
    background-color: rgba(250,240,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverme red"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme green"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme yellow"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme yellow works-but-not-nice"><div class="inner">this works</div></div>
```

So I'd like to change the opacity of background color regardless of whether it's yellow, red or whatever. Background images or content should always be fully opaque.

Bonus points for doing this without adding more div elements.

Comment: What's the problem with writing a `:hover` rule for the `.red` and `.green` classes or using `opacity:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case I would consider the use of CSS variable on where I define the value of opacity that I change on hover:

```css
:root {
  --opacity:0.8;
}
.hoverme {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    background-color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverme:hover .inner {
   --opacity:1;
}
.hoverme .inner {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.hoverme.red .inner {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,var(--opacity));
}
.hoverme.green .inner {
    background-color: rgba(0,200,0,var(--opacity));
}
.hoverme.yellow .inner {
    background-color: rgba(250,240,0,var(--opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverme red"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme green"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme yellow"><div class="inner">text</div></div>
```

Comment: Perfect..and so simple.

Comment: Wow. I had absolutely no idea you can do that. I thought CSS variables are constant. That changes so many things! Thank you a lot for this answer!

Comment: @TomášZato well, they are called variables :) so you can vary them ;) and you will see that you can do a lot of magic wit them :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hoverme {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    background-color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverme:hover .inner {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.hoverme .inner {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.hoverme.red .inner {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    opacity: .9;
}
.hoverme.green .inner {
    background-color: rgb(0,200,0);
    opacity: .9;
}
.hoverme.yellow .inner {
    background-color: rgb(250,240,0);
    opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverme red"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme green"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme yellow"><div class="inner">text</div></div>
```

Comment: I understood that he wants to change the opacity of the background colour, not the opacity of the whole button

Answer (score 0):

For '.hoverme .inner' add 'background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)' and for '.hoverme:hover .inner' add 'background: rgba(0,0,0,0)' - it will add transparent black background to inner element and it will set opacity of this background to 0 on hover. Then this each background colors add just to each of 'hoverme' elements, not to 'inner' and remove all opacity rules etc. Full code below:

```css
.hoverme {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverme .inner {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.hoverme:hover .inner {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.hoverme.red {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
.hoverme.green {
    background-color: rgb(0,200,0);
}
.hoverme.yellow {
    background-color: rgb(250,240,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverme red"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme green"><div class="inner">text</div></div>

<div class="hoverme yellow"><div class="inner">text</div></div>
```