# Css Background Color Opacity

Tags: html, css, background-color

I would like to add a darkened background color to my buttons when someone hovers over them. My problem is that the buttons have a `background-color: transparent` by default (when not being hovered over).

So that means the buttons have different background colors (depending on the background div's color). Therefore I cannot make 20+ css classes for every darkened color. I would like a solution that I can just add to my single icon-button class. See my examples for a better explanation.

I would like something like this:

```
.icon-button:hover {
    background-color: black;
    background-color-opacity: 25%;
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
.icon-button.white:hover {
    background-color: #xxxxxx; (darkened white)
}

.icon-button.red:hover {
    background-color: #xxxxxx; (darkened red)
}

.icon-button.purple:hover {
    background-color: #xxxxxx; (darkened purple)
}

.icon-button.green:hover {
    background-color: #xxxxxx; (darkened green)
}

.....
```

(For some reason my image upload is failing, check it here)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn9MR.jpg

Comment: Does this answer help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009479/css-class-to-lighten-background-color

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [rgba](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()) colour for the background. `rgba` has an alpha channel that dictates the opacity of the colour layer. This would be the equivalent of the `background-color-opacity` that you mention.

```css
div {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">
    Button
  </button>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button">
    Button
  </button>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: My dear friend, this is an AMAZING answer. Thank you very much :)

Comment: why you reopened the post? it was a perfect duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847205/change-background-color-opacity-without-changing-background-image-opacity

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't believe it is a dupe of that question. This is about overlaying a darkened colour over a parent elements background colour. The dupe is about changing the background colour of the element itself.

Comment: Sorry but they are exactly the same for me ... even your answer is similar to one there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48847757/8620333). wording are different but the visual result is the same

Comment: Close it if you want. It's no skin off my nose.

Comment: we cannot close twice ;)